# VSTO: Excel Resize range in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

I am trying to switch from VBA to VSTO, but I am experiencing some errors that I am not familiar with when I am trying to resize a range.

I have the code below which should end up being able to split a range of cells up in x numbers of rows.

I have created the project in VSTO as an add-in. When I run the code by pressing the button in Excel Visual Studo gives me an "COMExeption was unhandled by user code" and it highligts the last line, where I am trying to resize and output the range.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
    Dim inputrange As Excel.Range
    'Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim numberOfOutputRows As Long
    Dim numberOfOutPutColumns As Long
    Dim outputRange As Excel.Range
    Dim inputArray(0, 0) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim numberOfCells As Long
    Dim arrayInputValue As Excel.Range
    Dim val As Object


    inputrange = CType(sheet.Application.InputBox("select range",,,,,,, Type:=8), Excel.Range)

    'Dim myRange As Excel.Range

    numberOfOutputRows = InputBox("You have " & inputrange.Count & " cells. Enter the number of rows you want to split up in")

    numberOfOutPutColumns = inputrange.Cells.Count / numberOfOutputRows

    outputRange = CType(sheet.Application.InputBox("Output to single cell",,,,,,, Type:=8), Excel.Range)

    inputrange = inputrange.Columns(1)

    ReDim inputArray(0 To numberOfOutputRows, 0 To numberOfOutPutColumns + 1)

    numberOfCells = inputrange.Cells.Count - 1

    For i = 0 To numberOfCells
        arrayInputValue = CType(inputrange.Cells(i + 1), Excel.Range)
        val = arrayInputValue.value()
        iRow = i Mod numberOfOutputRows
        iCol = Int(i / numberOfOutputRows)
        inputArray(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = val  ' arrayInputValue
    Next i

    outputRange.Resize(RowSize:=UBound(inputArray, 1), ColumnSize:=UBound(inputArray, 2)).Value = inputArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare your output array to Object instead of Long

```
Dim inputArray(0, 0) As Object
```

VSTO reads/writes data from/to cells as object.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I also have some other issues since I loose some of the values filled into the inputArray - Can you help on that?

Comment: It should work the same way as it works in VBA. Did you try it in VBA (with some slight modification)? You know that you can debug your code in Visual Studio and see what exactly is going to be written in your array, right?
I didn't try it to be hones, let me know if you can't figure it out and I'll try to help you

Comment: I have tried it in VBA and it works perfect. I have some slight modification tough. I am not familiar with the debuggen Visual studio, how is that done? I will paste the VBA code here but I don't have enough characters.

Comment: OK, in the VS project, go to Project - Properties (the last item), then on the left side there are menus like Application, Compile, Debug etc. Navigate to Debug then there is an option Start Action - Start external program, navigate to C:\Program Files .... where the Excel.exe is located then put a breakpoint in your code e.g. select a line with 'numberOfOutputRows' and press F9 (this will place a breakpoint) and then run the project (F5) the code should stop on the breakpoint then you can use F10/F11 to step line by line